# Calculating the parent tile coordinates in google maps

Tags: google-maps

How can I most efficiently calculate a given tile's parent tile coordinates?
Let say I have a tile with coordinates:

```
x = 2194
y = 1287
z = 12
```

How can I then calculate its parent tile's coordinates in zoom 11?

Answer (score 3):

Google Maps is using a quad tree representation to calculate the indizes of their tiles. You can find an example on how the addressing system works [here](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/). In this link there is also a class available with many utility methods for conversions.

In general the parent tile should be available if you divide (and optionally round down) both x and y values:

```
x = 1097
y = 643
z = 11
```